# Microsoft Movie Maker Not Centering Video on Preview Screen

Tags: windows-movie-maker

I have a 2 hour deadline and I'm literally having a mental break down over this piece of crap software.

First of all, it doesn't process MOV files. Why make a video editing software at all?

Now after painstaking converting over 2000 MB of files into avi (over an extremely slow internet connection), the software refuses to center the video.

When I first started it, the video was centered on the preview screen just as it should. I think I clicked on add title, and now the video is pinned to the upper left corner, leaving a black screen in the middle.

[image]

Has anyone ever experienced this issue? There seems to be little to no solution to be found online.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Lightworks to spare you the hassle with WMM in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is a little late but but did you ever figure it out? I wouldn't recommend using windows movie maker for much of anything. The reason it doesn't accept .mov files is because it's windows movie maker, a Microsoft product using microsoft proprietary files .AVI and .WMV... .MOV is quicktime which is Apple.

You mentioned that you converted over 2000MB of files over an extremely slow internet connection so I'm assuming you didn't use software on your machine. I would start by blaming the converted file. It could possibly be that  movie maker can see the file but once you start adding effects everything goes to crap.

windows movie maker has saved me in a last minute pinch when I needed to fix something for a powerpoint presentation and didn't have my studio with me, but other than that I would say purchase the correct software, hire a a pro, or don't take on 2 hour deadlines when you don't have the proper equipment.

Comment: .avi is not proprietary its a very simple RIFF based container that can be used by anyone on any system. The part about WMV is true.

Comment: @ProfessorSparkles You're correct. My bad. I think I really meant to say .WMV is the proprietary one, But .AVI can be used, and then .MOV is apple. Either way, thanks for catching that.